# Google API Picker getting 400 errors in console - when logging back to Google at logImpressions endpoint

Tags: google-api, google-picker

We have the Google Picker working, but have noticed that the picker code seems to be trying to log events to Google, and is getting 400 errors when doing so.

[image]

Looks like Google library code trying to talk to Google infrastructure:

[image]

Just a problem with the Google infrastructure, or is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem - it was that third party cookies were disabled (in Incognito mode).